# Some questions in the compactness of Sobolev space and Holder space

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness, sobolev-spaces, holder-spaces

Let $B_1$ be the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Define $A=\{u \in W^{1,2}(B_1)  : \|u\|_{ W^{1,2} } \leq 1\}$, $B= \{u \in L^{2}(B_1)  : \|u\|_{ L^2 } \leq 1\}$, $C=\{u \in C^{0,\alpha}(B_1)  : \|u\|_{ C^{0,\alpha} } \leq 1\}$ and $D=\{u \in C^{0,\beta}(B_1)  : \|u\|_{ C^{0,\beta} } \leq 1\}$ with $0<\alpha<\beta<1$.

Let $u_n$ be any sequence in $A$, we can find a convergent subsequence such that $u_n$ converges to some limiting function $u_\infty$ weakly in $W^{1,2}$ and strongly in $L^2$. By Fatou Lemma, it is observed that $u_\infty$ also belongs $A$. In this case, can I say $A$ is compact in $B$ (under the topology of $B$)?

Let $v_n$ be any sequence in $D$, we can find a convergent subsequence such that $v_n$ converges to some limiting function $v_\infty$ in $C^{0,\alpha}$ by Arzel`a–Ascoli theorem. By lower semi continuity of Holder norm, it is observed that $v_\infty$ also belongs $D$. In this case, can I say $D$ is compact in $C$ (under the topology of $C$)?

Here comes to the last question. For some sets $X \subset Y$, $X$ is compact in $X$ if and only if $X$ is compact in $Y$. If the above two assertions are true, then $A$ and $D$ are compact, I think it is weired. Can someone helps? Thanks!

Comment: The confusion in the third paragraph comes from the omission of the topology wrt which $X$ is compact. You carefully explained that in the 1st and 2nd paragraph.

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean that all the three statements are correct?

Comment: The three statements are correct. The conclusion of the third is false: $A$ is compact wrt to the topology of $B$, similar for $C$

Comment: I think that $A$ is compact in $B$ implies $A$ is compact in $A$. I find the compactness for subset in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_space#Compactness_of_subsets